# Euclidean Geometric Construction: Trisecting an arbitrary angle

Tags: euclidean-geometry, angle, geometric-construction

I am an undergraduate student hence I have much lack of math knowledge. I was playing with the euclidean structures and constructions and then I confused myself. I know an algebraic proof that we cannot trisect an angle because the angle of $ \pi/9 $ is not constructable (algebraically proven), but I cannot find the mistake in this math delirium, this math absurdity. In the below procedure  I tried to explain what I did and my question is that could this gives us second thoughts about trisecting angles? We know that it can't be truw but could you indicate my mistakes?
Thank you in advance and I really apologize about this.

Let’s assume that we have an arbitrary angle with edge at the point A.
[image: initial angle]
I followed the below process:

**First step: Circle construction.**
We construct a circle with center point $A$ (using compass), let’s name it $C_A$, which intersects the first side of the angle at point $B$ and the second side of the angle at the point $C$.
[image: 1st step]

**Second step: Finding Midpoint of a line segment.**
We draw the line segment $BC$ which connects the points $B$ and $C$. Using compass, we draw two circles with radius $BC$ and center $B$ and $C$ and we call the $C_B$  and $C_C$ respectively.
[image: 2nd step (i)]
The circles intersection of these circles are the points $D$ and $E$ and the line segment $DE$ which connects them is the mediator (line segment) of the line segment $BC$, which intersects it at the point $F$.
[image: 2nd step (ii)]

**Third step: Circle construction.**
We construct one more circle (using compass) with center the point $F$ and radius $FB$. Let’s call it $C_F$.
[image: 3rd step]

**Fourth step: Trisecting a semicircle (or constructing a half hexagon).**
Now we have to construct three circles (using compass) with the same radius $FB$ as follows:

- The first circle is created with center $B$, we name it $C_b$, and it intersects the circle $C_F$ at the point $G$.
  [image: 4th step (i)]
- The second circle is created with center $G$, we name it $C_G$, and it intersects the circle $C_F$ at the point $H$.
  [image: 4th step (ii)]
- The third circle is created with center $H$, we name it $C_G$, and it intersects the circle $C_F$ at the point $C$, because the triangles $BGF$, $GFH$ and $HFC$ are equilateral (we know it by construction).
  [image: 4th step (iii)]
  (We just trisected the semicircle.)

**Fifth step:  Rays constructions**
We draw the rays $AG$ and $AH$, which $AG$ ray starts at the point $A$ and passes through the point $G$ and starts at the point $A$ and $AH$ ray passes through the point $H$.
[image: 5th step]
Do the rays $AG$ and $AH$ trisect the angle between the rays $AB$ and $AC$?
[image: Final Result]

Comment: The angle $\frac {\pi}6$ is easy to construct.  Just bisect an angle in an equilateral triangle.

Comment: I learnt how to construct $\pi/6$ when I was in mid-school…

Comment: Can you construct the angle $\pi/9$?

Comment: Dear @lulu, I am really sorry for being confusing.You are right!! I was thinking about the angle $ \pi/9$. I am going to edit my question.Thank you!!

Comment: Dear @Angina, I know the algebraic proof using the degree of the extension field over the field of the euclidean plane shows us that it cannot be done. But, I am confused because it seems that the above construction algorithm seems to give three equal parts of the initial angle. Therefore, I am sure that I have done a mistake but I cannot find it.

Comment: It is possible that you have found a neusis construction, which is a method that breaks the compass-and-straightedge rules. See the constructions on [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nonagon) for example.

Comment: It does not trisect the angle. If the angle is small to start with (i.e. A is far away from your construction between B and C), then the middle part of the "trisected" angle is almost twice the size of each of the other parts, because the rays are almost parallel and the middle section of the half-hexagon is twice the width of the outer parts. If the initial angle is 45, the middle part is 17.3, not 15.

Comment: Dear @JaapScherphuis, I really thank you for your helpful note!! I couldn't notice that without your help. Thank you very much!!

Comment: By the way, I did assume you constructed the half-hexagon on the side of $BC$ opposite to $A$, though you did not say so. If you were to construct the half-hexagon on the inside, the discrepancy is worse.

Comment: @P4N05EV.: It looks like you've used GeoGebra to create accurate drawings; this is helpful. Now, note that GeoGebra has an "angle" tool that lets you measure the angles you've drawn; use that to see if your three angles have equal sizes. (I'd say that the thick-lines version of your drawing should be enough to raise suspicion: there's more apparent "overlap" of the sides of the outer two angles than of the middle one, strongly suggesting that the middle angle is slightly larger than its neighbors.)

Comment: Thank all of you for your help. Problem solved!! using Geogebra it proved that the middle angle is much greater than the other two. The mistake must be the one which has been spoted by @JaapScherphuis. 
Thank you!! 
Best regards